# what is wrong with the logic that i am using?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, nested-loops

theres a logic error , for the code i m trying to do ,

```
  *
 **
***
 **
  *
```

so this is the pattern , what my code is running is this

```
  *
 **
***
 **
  **
   **
```

there seems to be logic error for the printing of stars , i just wanted to know what logic should i use.
heres the code :-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    /*

       *
      **
     ***
      **
       *

    */
    int i,rows;
    cout<<"Enter number of rows :"<<endl;
    cin>>rows;
    for(i = 1; i <= ((rows/2)+1) ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = (rows  - i); j >= 1; j--)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(i = ((rows/2)+1) ; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for(int k = (rows/2); k >= 1; k--)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << "  *\n
 **\n
***\n
 **\n
  *\n";` - problem solved 

Comment: what  if user inputs  n lol , code says for 5  , but i want to make a universal code

Answer (score 1):

You can change your second loop as follows:

```
for ( i = ( rows / 2 ); i >= 1; i-- ) {
    for ( int j = ( rows - i ); j >= 1; j-- ) {
        cout << " ";
    }
    for ( int k = 1; k <= i; k++ ) {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

It reuses the logic from the first loop, but just changes it to go from `rows/2` down to `1` (inclusive) instead.

The first loop header also runs too many times for even values. For example, with `4`, it does `4 / 2 + 1` which is `3`. What you want is below.

```
for ( i = 1; i <= (int)( rows / 2. + .5 ); i++ )
```

This effectively rounds. So for `4` you now have `4 / 2. + .5` which is `2.5`, then converted to `int` is `2`. With `5`, you get `5 / 2. + .5` which is `2.5 + .5` which is `3.0`, then to an `int` is `3`

Comment: wait , the loop wont work for even numbers now , on inputting 4, it runs same as 5

Comment: That would be a problem in the first for loop's header going 1 too many. I've updated the answer with the proper loop header for the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize `i` in the second `for` loop.  Just let continue with the next row value after the first loop finishes.

The number of `*` you print is controlled by the `k` loop.  In the first row loop you print out `i` of them, while in the second you always print out the same number - `rows / 2`.  You'll want to print out a gradually reducing number of them - `rows + 1 - i`.  Or just use `for (int k = i; k <= rows; ++k)`.